# Encapsulating AWS Lambda environment variable access in Java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

As our AWS Lambda deployment grows, there are more and more scattered environment variables being read via `System.getenv()`. I didn't find what can be considered the best practice managing all those vars.

An obvious solution would be to refactor it to Spring/Guice and use configurers, but considering we keep it as close to plain old java as possible to reduce the JAR size, what can be considered a good strategy encapsulating the configuration? Apache Commons Configuration? Building a custom Configuration/Env class?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some language-agnostic guidance on [Choosing the right solution for AWS Lambda external parameters](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-the-right-solution-for-aws-lambda-external-parameters/).

Answer (score 0):

So I guess one really inefficient way to handle that is to actually scatter the environment references in the code:

```
if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getenv("ENABLE_FEATURE_X"))) {
  // enable the feature
}
```

It gets the job done but there are two big side-effects:

- Mocking `System.getenv` is not ideal
- DRY principle is violated

I wonder if introducing `Env` or `Context` class might be an easy enough workaround?

```
Env env = Env.getInstance()
if (env.isFeatureEnabled()) {
  // enable the feature
}
```